# Importing Numpy into functions

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

I do not know the right way to import modules.

I have a main file which initializes the code, does some preliminary calculations etc.
I also have 5 functions f1, f2, ... f5. The main code and all functions need Numpy.

If I define all functions in the main file, the code runs fine.
(Importing with : `import numpy as np`)

If I put the functions in a separate file, I get an error:
`Error : Global name 'linalg' is not defined.`

What is the right way to import modules such that the functions f1 - f5 can access the Numpy functionality?

Comment: import numpy at the beginning of every file, if it's been imported once, it won't import again, but you will have the namespace to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other answers say, you need to import numpy into each file where you call a Numpy function.   However you don't need to import it into the main module if you're not using it in the main module.  Here's a simple example.  Imagine you have a file with your function in it called myFunc.py
myFunc.py:

```
import numpy as np

def f1(a):  # a is a numpy multidimensional array
    z = np.array(a)
    flat = z.ravel()
    flat = flat.tolist()

    return flat
```

Then in your main file you can do something like this

```
import myFunc as mf

mf.f1([[4,67,8],[7,9,7]])
```

Your output will be:

```
[4, 67, 8, 7, 9, 7]
```

So you pass a list to your function, convert it to a numpy array in your function, then return the answer as a list.  If you return a numpy array you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import modules in every file in which you use them.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I thought that was repetitious and the right way was to just import them once. Thanks.